# Get the value of a tag which has another tag before its value with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Searched around for a bit but couldn't find any post that matches my problem.
Say I have this html:

```
<div id=a>
    <span>junk</span>
    content
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to get "content"? 
`doc.find(id="a").string` returns None 
`doc.find(id="a").text` return "junk content"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

- find all text nodes with `recursive=False` and get the last one:

  ```
  div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)[-1]
  ```
- get the `span`'s element [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

  ```
  div.span.next_sibling.strip()
  ```
- get the last element from the [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

  ```
  div.contents[-1].strip()
  ```

where `div = doc.find(id="a")`.